# how to make an ammo limit decrease from its current value, after it has been increased in C#, Unity?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, reference, static

my character shoots arrows. She starts without zero arrows and cannot shoot any until she picks up an arrow icon. Arrow icons have a value of 3. After this she can shoot arrows. That code works fine. Now I have to make it so these arrows decrease in value through the UI text display. The UI text value changes from 0 to 3 when an arrow icon is picked up, but it doesn't decrease when I shoot an arrow. I have another game object with a script that will detect when an arrow is shot. when this happens, it tells that main script that, "hey, an arrow was just shot." The focus is on getting the Text to decrease when I shoot an arrow.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class arrowManager : MonoBehaviour {

private Text text;
public static int arrowCount;
public static int arrowRecount;
private int maxArrows = 99;

void Start ()
{
    text = GetComponent<Text> ();
    arrowCount = 0;
}

void Update ()
{
    FullQuiver ();
    arrowCounter ();
}

void arrowCounter()
{
    if (arrowCount < 0) {
        arrowCount = 0;
        text.text = "" + arrowCount;
    }
    if (arrowCount > 0)
        text.text = "" + arrowCount;
}
public static void AddPoints(int pointsToAdd)
{
    arrowCount += pointsToAdd;
}
public static void SubtractPoints(int pointsToSubtract)
{
    arrowCount -= pointsToSubtract;
}

public void FullQuiver()
{
    if (arrowCount >= maxArrows)
    {
        arrowCount = maxArrows;
    }
}
}
```

the game object with the script that detects arrows looks like this.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class arrowDetector : MonoBehaviour {


public int pointsToSubtract;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "arrow")
    {
        arrowManager.SubtractPoints (pointsToSubtract);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Can you place a `Debug.Log()` inside the Trigger method? Just to see if it is even called.

Comment: Yes, Debug it, i think if you fire your arrows, you need to use raycast to solve your problem, sometimes because of fps and speed of your arrow, you will miss your triggers. check your gameobjects that have rigidbody components too and colliders...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Before, I was trying to get it to detect my arrows whenever a bool became true from my player script. That wasn't working so I said screw it and just made an empty that detects gameobjects with the tag "arrow." Then I updated the script in here to reflect that. I was dead tired last night after not getting any sleep for two days so I forgot to put in a value of pointsToSubtract in the hierarchy. Thanks everyone for their responses.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I've misunderstood, but it looks to me like you are subtracting from the wrong variable.

Since you are displaying the 'arrowCount' variable, I imagine that's what should be subtracted from.

```
public static void SubtractPoints(int pointsToSubtract)
{
    if (arrowCount > 0) {

        arrowCount -= pointsToSubtract;//pointsToSubtract is an int value passed to this script from my player script whenever she shoots an arrow.
    }
}
```

Comment: okay it's back to the way it originally was (how you typed it in fact). The results are the same however.

Answer (score 0):

In SubtractPoints method you are detracting from the variable "arrowRecount".
Wouldn't you want to be subtracting from "arrowCount" instead? If you used "arrowCount" your text value should update properly.

Comment: yea i tried that too in various ways but got the same results. So i tried a different variable to no avail :(